# Get pixels inside a patch

Tags: matplotlib

In matplotlib, it's possible to get the pixels inside a polygon using `matplotlib.nxutils.points_inside_poly`, as long as you have vertices defined beforehand.

How can you get the points inside a patch, e.g. an ellipse?

The problem: if you define a matplotlib ellipse, it has a `.get_verts()` method, but this returns the vertices in figure (instead of data) units.

One could do:

```
# there has to be a better way to do this, 
# but this gets xy into the form used by points_inside_poly
xy = np.array([(x,y) for x,y in zip(pts[0].ravel(),pts[1].ravel())]) 
inds =  np.array([E.contains_point((x,y)) for x,y in xy], dtype='bool')
```

However, this is very slow since it's looping in python instead of C.

Comment: You can use the transforms to change the units to data and than make a poly out of it, I think.

Comment: @tcaswell - I think that's true.  In that case, the question should be interpreted as, "How do I use transforms to convert the verts..."

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer (sorry), but this http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html should get you most of the way to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ax.transData.transform()` to transform your points, and then use `points_inside_poly()`:

```
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.nxutils import points_inside_poly
import numpy as np

fig, ax = pl.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
e = mpatches.Ellipse((1, 2), 3, 1.5, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_patch(e)
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale()

p = e.get_path()
points = np.random.normal(size=(1000, 2))
polygon = e.get_verts()
tpoints = ax.transData.transform(points)
inpoints = points[points_inside_poly(tpoints, polygon)]
sx, sy = inpoints.T
ax.scatter(sx, sy)
```

result:

[image]